# Media query works with bootstrap classes but not with my id or class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm a little new to this, so apologies if it's a dumb question, just can't find the answer elsewhere.

I am building a form with several groups of colspan 6 to create the effect of 2 columns. I need to raise a group to cover some empty space when a large viewport is in use. I have the following CSS which works on the form:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .dxbs-fl-gt.col-lg-6.col-12 {
    position: relative;
    top: -105px;
  }
}
```

That's all well and dandy until I check out a similar form and see that one of its groups is now raised making that form look off. In order to affect just the 1st form, I tried replacing the bootstrap classes (`.dxbs-fl-gt.col-lg-6.col-12`) with a div class (and then an id because it's just for this one spot), but it's as if that CSS is now ignored totally. Here is my new CSS for the sake of thoroughness:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  #vendorAddressGroup {
    position: relative;
    top: -105px;
  }
}
```

I've tried moving my div tags to several places all of which surround the group, but no joy. Can anyone advise on what to try next?

My HTML:

```
                        <div id="vendorAddressGroup">
                            <DxFormLayoutTabPages ColSpanXs="12"
                                                  ColSpanLg="6"
                                                  ActiveTabIndex="@ActiveTabIndex1">
                                <DxFormLayoutTabPage Caption="Main">
                                    @switch (ActiveTabIndex1)
                                    {
                                        case 0:
                                            @*Address Group*@

                                            <DxFormLayoutGroup Caption="Address"
                                                               ColSpanXs="12"
                                                               ColSpanMd="12"
                                                               ColSpanLg="12">
                                                @*Various <DxFormLayoutItem>s*@
                                            </DxFormLayoutGroup>
                                            @*Contact Group*@
                                            <DxFormLayoutGroup Caption="Contact"
                                                               ColSpanXs="12"
                                                               ColSpanMd="12"
                                                               ColSpanLg="12">
                                                @*Various <DxFormLayoutItem>s*@
                                            </DxFormLayoutGroup>

                                            break;
                                    }
                                </DxFormLayoutTabPage>

                                <DxFormLayoutTabPage />
                                <DxFormLayoutTabPage />
                                <DxFormLayoutTabPage />
                            </DxFormLayoutTabPages>
                        </div>
```

Comment: If your ID doesn't work there is a good chance it's because you have the ID multiple times on the page. You could just use a class?

Comment: Could you show us the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thanks @Dominik, but the ID is used only once.

Comment: Another reason an ID selector isn't working is because it's misspelled. Can you please share your HTML and use the snippet function here in SO to re-produce this issue?

Comment: @Dominik, it's posted. BTW, this is in C# Blazor using DevExpress. Looking for a good place in which to provide an example.

Comment: @AHaworth, it is now posted.

Comment: @BlazorWolf why not inspect the page in your browser and copy the rendered HTML out?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you created a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - that means the minimal chunk of rendered HTML and CSS that anyone can immediately view in a browser and see the problem.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I would like to, but the DevExpress part makes it particularly difficult if not impossible to use Codepen, JSfiddle, etc. Sent in a ticket to DevEx, though I'm unsure it relates to their product specifically.

Comment: If you're building an HTML page/application, you can presumably view it in a browser right?  So view source, and copy out the smallest necessary chunk to reproduce the problem :-)

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic, I did Ctrl-U, but I don't know how to best share it with you and SO, and I haven't had any luck Googling it. I hate to ask you for more help, but... any ideas on this? - Thanks

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem.  Paste your HTML and CSS in your question. If you can spend time first reducing it to the **minimal** amount of HTML/CSS necessary to reproduce the problem, you're more likely to get help.  Have you tried using your browser's devtools to inspect the CSS?  By clicking on HTML elements you will be able to see the hierarchy of applied styles, eg click on your ID and maybe you will get some clues about why your style isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per DevEx, need to get DevEx Blazor 21.1.5, "wrap tabs in the DxFormLayoutGroup element and specify the CssClass property for this element. Then, you can use this CSS class to create a media query specific to that group." Can't update yet so can't test it, but sounds promising.